# Finding the radius of convergence of this power series involving logarithms

Tags: real-analysis

As the title says, I'm looking for the radius of convergence of this power series: $$\sum\limits_{k=3}^\infty (\log k)^{k/2}x^k$$ where "$\log$" denotes the natural logarithm.

I suspect I need to use the ratio test (since we have not proved any other methods in class); dividing the absolute values of successive terms, I get $$|x|\frac{(\log(k+1))^{\frac{k+1}{2}}}{(\log k)^{k/2}}$$

Now there is probably a specific step I need to take towards simplifying this before I take the limit as $k \rightarrow \infty$, but I'm just not seeing it.

Please only hints, not full solutions, in your answers

Comment: You may want to try the root test instead.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned - we have not proved the root test, so I think it's best if I don't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $${\log(k+1)^{\frac{k+1}2}\over\log k^{\frac k2}}>{\log(k+1)^{\frac{k+1}2}\over\log(k+1)^{\frac k2}}$$.

I think that will get you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Hah, tonight is not my night. So since the limit of the right hand side is $\infty$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$, so is the left side, and therefore the series never converges?

Comment: Only converges for $x=0$.

Comment: Right, thanks for your help

Comment: Your quite welcome.